# AJAX POST to send serialized and unserialzed data at the same time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I was wondering if it is possible to send a serialized form and non-serialized data in a $.ajax post. I realize I kind of dug myself into a hole otherwise. I am trying to add and update table rows. My PHP file is expecting first an 'add' or 'edit' to come in, then process serialized data.

PHP - there is one for add and edit

```
if(isset($_POST['func']))}
 if($_POST['func']=='add_table_name'){
  if(isset($_POST['... all of the form inputs ... ']).........
```

My jquery function

```
function tableAction(tableId, tableFunc, rowId, callback){  
  tableURL = "php/table_" + tableId + ".php";
  tableData = { func : tableFunc + '_' + tableId, rowId : rowId };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: tableURL,
    data: tableData,
    success: function (data) {
        if(data){;
            if (callback){      
                    callback(data);
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I call it like

```
tableAction(tableId, 'add', rowId, function()....
```

As you can see there is currently nowhere to input the form data. I was wondering if it can be serialized and then added to the data, something like

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
....
....
  data: tableData + formData,
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I used $.extend

var formData = $('form').serialize();

$.extend(tableData,formData);